# Magento class not found

Tags: php, xml, magento, spl-autoload-register

I have written a payment plugin in magento and it works (almost) flawlessly. Frontend payments are getting through I thought everything is done. But now I stumbled upon an issue.

I am using own autoloader and the registering event is `controller_front_init_before` which works fine. When I create a script calling `Mage::app();` and then when I try to edit the orders I get from `Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection();` I get an error that my classes aren't loaded. I tried changing the event even to `resource_get_tablename` but the error persists. The only way to fix this error was to register the same autoloader I use in my plugin in the small script and this is an issue for me. Script follows

```
require_once "app/Mage.php";

Mage::app();
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection();

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    echo "ORDER id " . $order->getId() . " #" . $order->getIncrementId()."\n";
    $order->setData('status',Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    $order->save();
}
```

Is anybody here who knows maybe which event to use so that this script works without needing to use `spl_autoload_register...` method?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

*code/communinty/Payment/Module/config.xml*

```
<config>
  <global>
    <events>
      <resource_get_tablename>
        <observers>
          <payment_module>
            <class>Payment_Module_Model_Autoloader</class>
            <method>addAutoloader</method>
            <type>singleton</type>
          </payment_module>
        </observers>
      </resource_get_tablename>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

*code/community/Payment/Module/Model/Autoloader.php*

```
class Payment_Module_Model_Autoloader extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    protected static $registered = false;

    public function addAutoloader(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (self::$registered) {
            return;
        }
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoload'), false, true);
        self::$registered = true;
    }

    public function autoload($class)
    {
       $classFile = COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php';
       include $classFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: please give autoloader code that you used in your script so that we solve.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I added both the autoloader and the xml